# How to compare Dates in XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0, soa, wso2-esb

I am using XSLT version 1.0. I want to compare two dates( > or < or =).

Can any one help me? Below are the dates which I want to compare

1.2016-07-11 05:00:00
2.2016-07-11 06:00:00

Thanks.

Comment: @stefan With XSLT and XPath 1.0 the `<` operator does not work for strings, see https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#booleans. For strings you can only do `=` and `!=`.

Comment: Iih, my bad -throw it away

Answer (score 1, accepted):

XSLT 1.0 has no concept of dates and cannot compare them as such.

However, you can easily convert the given dates to comparable *numerical* values. For example:

```
translate($date1, '- :', '') &lt; translate($date2, '- :', '')
```

will return `true`.